Glob pattern to read in a specific string in Python
I have a folder with a list of files I want to read in as a list of full file paths.
The files that I want to read in have this structure: [0-9]_beta_[Y].nii.gz, where:

[0-9] is a 3 digit sequence of numbers (e.g. 123)
[Y] is a character string of any length (e.g. 'faces', 'faces_up')

What is the right pattern for this?
Here's the code I have so far but it doesn't get all the files I need:
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_dir, f'*_beta_*nii.gz'))

Thanks so much for your help!

Can you give an example of a file it should return but doesn't?

I think it should return all the files. But it may return additional files, since the first * isn't limited to 3 characters or only digits.

Try:
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '[0-9][0-9][0-9]_beta_*.nii.gz'))

[0-9][0-9][0-9] matches exactly 3 digits, your * matches anything. And you should have . before nii.gz.
The string doesn't need to be an f-string, you're not substituting anything into it.
